# Should the tag of a derived package (pgfplots)'s parent package (tikz-pgf) also be applied?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Recently, I've seen some questions about [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) posted that were only tagged [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) at the time of posting:

- [Improving a tikz plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232369/improving-a-tikz-plot)
- [ybar stacked: Position of labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232049/ybar-stacked-position-of-labels)
- [How to plot with tikz without graduations in the axis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227476/how-to-plot-with-tikz-without-graduations-in-the-axis)

I've been editing the tags to add [pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots), of course. But I'm wondering if leaving [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) adds anything for questions strictly about `pgfplots`. `pgfplots` is built on top of Ti*k*Z/`pgf`, but it has its own set of commands, keys, and conventions.

To be sure, there *are* questions that concern aspects of both packages (using `\draw` and `\node` commands inside `axis` environments, for instance), and for these, both tags make sense.

Should questions about only `pgfplots` functionality (for example, `\addplot` commands and keys defined in `pgfplots` itself) be tagged simply [pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots) or including both [pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots) *and* [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf)?

Comment: I agree, for questions that are only concerned with PGFPlots and not with the interaction between PGFPlots and "just" TikZ, there's no use in having the [tag:tikz-pgf] tag.

Comment: Me too but other than us retagging I don't know any other way to explain the difference to users. My colleague after almost 3 years still says: *I drew this plot in TikZ*

Comment: @percusse By a better UI. PGFplot is currently enclosed in `\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis} ...`.

Comment: @yo' You can still do many cool stuff before and after axis environment and within TikZ picture. So it is for a reason.